# How to assign column variable 'Date' with Date value from a column header in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data inputs that I am reading via pandas.

[image]

[image]

I want to take the cell 'Month Ending .....'  and drop into a newly formed 'Date' Column and append the two input files together into one dataframe.

This is what I have tried so far...

```
import pandas as pd    
import glob 
import os 


### List Source Files That I need to Import###
path  = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)

### Loading Files by Variable ###

data = pd.DataFrame()


for files in glob.glob('../Sales_Master_Data/Sales_Data/* customer *.xls'): #searches for customer .xls files in the folder

    data = pd.read_excel(files,'sheet1',skiprows=0).fillna(method='ffill')#reads all files in df
    date = data.columns[4] # This is where the date value is located
    data['Date'] = date # Assigns date value to new ['Date'] column
    df  = df.append(data) # all files are appended together
    df.to_csv('Output.csv')
```

Unfortunately it produces the output below. All cols beginning with 'Month' need to be merged into 1 column and called ['Sales Qty'] and I'm also having trouble tiding up the column headers so that they are uniform[image]

Ideal output would look like this.....
[image]

Comment: what do you mean by drop a cell into a new column?

Comment: I want to take the value from the cell ('Month Ending .....') , create a column called 'Date' and store the value in Date as a row

Comment: can you include the output of your 'print (data)' statement ?

Comment: I have updated to make it more clear @Gerardo Flores

Comment: This might also help: https://github.com/ZaxR/pandas_multiindex_tutorial/blob/master/Pandas%20MultiIndex%20Tutorial.ipynb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never a good  idea to feed merged cells into pandas. First thing I would suggest is to flatten your inputs. If there is no easy way to do so and to answer your original question, you need to create a multiindex dataframe to handle your data best. This has already been covered in StackOverflow here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424102/9754169](http://It%20is%20never%20a%20good%20%20idea%20to%20feed%20merged%20cells%20into%20pandas.%20First%20thing%20I%20would%20suggest%20is%20to%20flatten%20your%20inputs.%20To%20answer%20your%20original%20question,%20you%20need%20to%20create%20a%20multiindex%20dataframe%20to%20handle%20your%20data%20best.%20This%20has%20already%20been%20covered%20in%20StackOverflow%20here:%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424102/9754169)