# pandas: split merged header from excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i have an excel file with merged header like this

[image: my excel header]

what i want is header like this using pandas

[image: what i lookin for]

I tried using this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27424102/12934577

but it return
`sequence item 0: expected str instance, float found`

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use `str` instead like in that answer:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0:2].apply(lambda x: '.'.join([str(y) for y in x if y]), axis=0)
```

Comment: thank you, but the NaN value below a,b and c (because it was merged) is still there it just transform too "_"