# How to read merged Excel cells with NaN into Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I would like to read an Excel sheet into Pandas DataFrame. However, there are merged Excel cells as well as Null rows (full/partial `NaN` filled), as shown below. To clarify, John H. has made an order to purchase all the albums from "The Bodyguard" to "Red Pill Blues".

[image: Excel sheet capture]

When I read this Excel sheet into a Pandas DataFrame, the Excel data does not get transferred correctly. Pandas considers a merged cell as one cell. The DataFrame looks like the following: *(Note: Values in () are the desired values that I would like to have there)*

[image: Dataframe capture]

Please note that the last row does not contain merged cells; it only carries a value for `Artist` column.

---

**EDIT:**
I did try the following to forward-fill in the NaN values:([Pandas: Reading Excel with merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937650/pandas-reading-excel-with-merged-cells))

```
df.index = pd.Series(df.index).fillna(method='ffill')
```

However, the `NaN` values remain. **What strategy or method could I use to populate the DataFrame correctly?** Is there a Pandas method of unmerging the cells and duplicating the corresponding contents?

Comment: Did you try anything? Can you show us your attempt? May this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937650/pandas-reading-excel-with-merged-cells

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas: Reading Excel with merged cells](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937650/pandas-reading-excel-with-merged-cells)

Comment: @Vico - not just helpful, it's the exact same question!

Comment: @ Vico - I already tried the solution in the link, however, it does not work. The `NaN` values remain.

Answer (score 10):

The referenced link you attempted needed to forward fill only the **index** column. For your use case, you need to `fillna` for **all** dataframe columns. So, simply forward fill entire dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_excel("Input.xlsx")
print(df)

#    Order_ID Customer_name            Album_Name           Artist  Quantity
# 0       NaN           NaN            RadioShake              NaN       NaN
# 1       1.0       John H.         The Bodyguard  Whitney Houston       2.0
# 2       NaN           NaN              Lemonade          Beyonce       1.0
# 3       NaN           NaN  The Thrill Of It All        Sam Smith       2.0
# 4       NaN           NaN              Thriller  Michael Jackson      11.0
# 5       NaN           NaN                Divide       Ed Sheeran       4.0
# 6       NaN           NaN            Reputation     Taylor Swift       3.0
# 7       NaN           NaN        Red Pill Blues         Maroon 5       5.0

df = df.fillna(method='ffill')
print(df)

#    Order_ID Customer_name            Album_Name           Artist  Quantity
# 0       NaN           NaN            RadioShake              NaN       NaN
# 1       1.0       John H.         The Bodyguard  Whitney Houston       2.0
# 2       1.0       John H.              Lemonade          Beyonce       1.0
# 3       1.0       John H.  The Thrill Of It All        Sam Smith       2.0
# 4       1.0       John H.              Thriller  Michael Jackson      11.0
# 5       1.0       John H.                Divide       Ed Sheeran       4.0
# 6       1.0       John H.            Reputation     Taylor Swift       3.0
# 7       1.0       John H.        Red Pill Blues         Maroon 5       5.0
```

Comment: This would produce the wrong results for rows 10, 16 and 26 in the original table.

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional:

```
import pandas as pd

df_excel = pd.ExcelFile('Sales.xlsx')
df = df_excel.parse('Info')

for col in list(df):  # All columns
    pprow = 0
    prow = 1
    for row in df[1:].iterrows():  # All rows, except first
        if pd.isnull(df.loc[prow, 'Album Name']):  # If this cell is empty all in the same row too.
            continue
        elif pd.isnull(df.loc[prow, col]) and pd.isnull(df.loc[row[0], col]):  # If a cell and next one are empty, take previous valor. 
            df.loc[prow, col] = df.loc[pprow, col]
        pprow = prow
        prow = row[0]
```

Output (I use different names):

```
    Order_ID Customer_name    Album Name
0        NaN           NaN         Radio
1        1.0          John            a 
2        1.0          John             b
3        1.0          John             c
4        1.0          John             d
5        1.0          John             e
6        1.0          John             f
7        NaN           NaN            GE
8        2.0         Harry   We are Born
9        3.0        Lizzy        Relapse
10       4.0           Abe         Smoke
11       4.0           Abe       Tell me
12       NaN           NaN           NaN
13       NaN           NaN      Best Buy
14       5.0        Kristy      The wall
15       6.0         Sammy  Kind of blue
```

Comment: @ Manuel - I tried your solution, but I get the following error: `KeyError: the label [-1] is not in the [index]`. This error is caused from the last line of your code. Shouldn't the last line be `df.loc[row[0], col] = df.loc[row[0]+1, col]`? It would be appreciative if you can include in-line comments in your answer to explain your logic. I am new to Python Pandas and would like to better understand your logic here. Thank you.

Comment: @ Manuel - How does your solution regard the last row of my Excel sheet (screenshot above) where it is a normal row with unmerged cells. It looks as though this row is merged with the previous row (`Order_ID 15`), but this last row is its own.

Comment: @ Manuel - I retried your solution, but I am getting the same error because my DataFrame has index labels that go like this: `2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,12,...`. Thus, there is no row/index label `10`. I want to reset the index labels but for the project purposes, I cannot. How can I iterate a DataFrame (row-by-row) that has **non-sequential** index labels?

Comment: Now saves each row in 'prow', previous row and 'pprow' previous previous row. Now, there should be no problem even if the row numbers are not consecutive.

Comment: @ Manuel - Your updated code partially works for me. I tried to implement your solution into a dictionary of DataFrames (`df_dict = {sheet_name: Dataframe, sheet_name: Dataframe,...}`). I had a combination of results: for some of the dataframes, the merged cells are correctly filled in entirely while some DF's are partially filled & some retain the merged cells. There should be way to do this in a dictionary of multiple DataFrames...

Comment: @Mook If all the dataframes  have the same format, it should work. Test separately the cases that do not work.

Comment: While I've not tested it, this methodology should work, unlike the higher voted answer. Sadly this solution is very specific to this table structure.