# pandas read_excel ,reading a single header to multile columns

Tags: pandas

I have the following dataset:

[image]

I want to do the following:

```
dataset = pd.read_excel(datasets_dir + '\\' + dataset_filename,na_values="NULL")
if dataset['ExpectedWeight'][0][0] == 630:
   return True # This should work.
```

Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know exactly what you want to achieve but you should take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937650/pandas-reading-excel-with-merged-cells) about merged cells in excel and pandas.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you are asking for, but if you manually set your columns by the tag `headers` and started reading in the data form the second line, with the tag `skiprows` being 1, you could split the data into column names you need or just index them.