# Pandas iloc & loc & multi index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I have a dataframe like:

[image]

so I want add some columns by two "for loop" like:

new dataframe like picture:

[image]

my code does not work:

```
for I in range(0,len(df["date"]):
    for sigma in rang(1,2/5):
       df["P*sigma"].iloc[0:i]=df["p"].iloc[0:i]*df["sigma"].iloc[sigma]
print(df)
```

how do I write code   to obtain the dataframe like second picture?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, as pandas needs full rows, but you probably don't need it either. You should just have repeated values of sigma for each row where it is the same, the information content will be identical, see here for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937650/pandas-reading-excel-with-merged-cells

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a [MultiIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), which can be done in various ways, but I always prefer using `from_product()`.

Note that we will have to do some preparation before we can do this. We have to make sure the index is properly set on the original DataFrame, and we have to elongate the original DataFrame to allow the new rows.

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020/01/01', '2020/01/02', '2020/01/03'], 'p': [123, 231, 188]})
df = df.set_index('date')
sigma = [0, 1, 2, 5]

# Create new 2-level index
multi_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([sigma, df.index], names=['sigma', 'date'])

# Make longer
df = pd.concat([df] * len(sigma))

# Set new index
df = df.set_index(multi_index)

# Print result
print(df.head())
>>>                    p
>>> sigma p
>>> 0     2020/01/01  123
>>>       2020/01/02  231
>>>       2020/01/03  188
>>> 1     2020/01/01  123
>>>       2020/01/02  231
```

If you want to make new columns or use the index values, you can get those with `get_level_values()` like this:

```py
df["p*sigma"] = df.index.get_level_values("sigma") * df["p"]
print(df.head())
>>>                     p  p*sigma
>>> sigma date
>>> 0     2020/01/01  123        0
>>>       2020/01/02  231        0
>>>       2020/01/03  188        0
>>> 1     2020/01/01  123      123
```

Answer (score 0):

After adding rows and column "sigma" like this
You can use DataFrame.apply like

```
df["P*sigma"] = df.apply(lambda x: x["p"] * x["sigma"], axis=1)
```

Comment: but before this you have to multiply and add "sigma" column.

Answer (score 0):

In python you can repeate an array using the mulipliciation sign `*`. If you have the free columns `sigma`, `date` and `p` it is easy to define a DataFrame in the correct shape. To create the new column just do an element wise multiplication (there is no need for an `apply()` call. Afterwards you can set the index, if wanted.

```
import pandas as pd
sigma = [0.5, 1, 2, 2/5]
date = ['2020/01//02', '2020/01//03', '2020/01//04']
p = [123,231,188]

df = pd.DataFrame({'sigma':sigma*len(p), 'date':date*len(sigma), 'p':p*len(sigma)})
df['p*sigma'] = df['p']*df['sigma']
df.set_index(['sigma', 'date'], inplace=True)
>>>df
                     p  p*sigma
sigma date                     
0.5   2020/01//02  123     61.5
1.0   2020/01//03  231    231.0
2.0   2020/01//04  188    376.0
0.4   2020/01//02  123     49.2
0.5   2020/01//03  231    115.5
...
```